# to see something on the internet when you are not expecting to

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, spoken-english

How do you say that you saw something (e.g., someone's name, a piece of news, etc.) on the internet when you were not expecting to? In other words, I'm looking for a word/expression equivalent to `bump into` in the context of the internet. I think we should use *bump into* only when you meet someone by chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When talking about reading something unanticipated, a common expression is "to come across":

> While checking posts on this site I visit, I **came across** an interesting article about the International Space Station.

Other possibilities:  *stumble upon, uncover, chance upon, happen upon, hit upon*

You're right and "bump into" or "run into" tend to be used for chance *meetings* with people, not information.